# Get rid of unrequired columns in powershell Mysql query result that appear when convert-tohtml is used

Tags: powershell

I have this Powershell script that returns MySql query results in email.

The problem is with the required data it also prints some not rquired columns like 'RowError    RowState    Table   ItemArray   HasErrors'

[image]

Following is the code snippet -

```
$subject = "Release report - bug status"
$body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | convertto-html | out-string ;
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -body $body -bodyashtml -priority High
```

How to get rid of those columns?

Pls help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to simply select the data from your table that you do want when defining `$body`.

```
$body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | Select bug_id,Status,Resolution,Summary,Deadline | convertto-html | out-string
```

Or, you can select everything, and then specify what you want to exclude:

```
$body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | convertto-html | out-string
```